# Doubt-An Exponential Sum formed with Primes

Tags: analytic-number-theory

I am going through the chapter "An exponential sum formed with primes" from the book Multiplicative Number Theory, Davenport. However I am unable to understand the following inequality($\ll$).

$$M + \sum_{1 \leq m \leq N/M} \min\big(\frac{N}{m}, \frac{1}{\|m \alpha\|}\big) \ll\Big( M +\frac{N}M+\frac{N}{q}+q\Big)(\log qN)$$

What I know is $$\sum_{t \leq T} \min\Big(\frac{N}{t}, \frac{1}{\|t \alpha\|}\Big) \ll \Big(\frac Nq+T+q\Big)\log(2qT)$$

I am also uploading the image from the book for clarity[image: Davenport]

Comment: Replace $t$ with $m$ and $T$ with $N/M$, then use the fact that for $N \geq 2$, $\log \frac{2N}{M} = \log 2 + \log \frac{N}{M} \leq \log N + \log N = 2 \log N \ll \log N$.